# append data in createReadStream in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, stream, electron

I have a node.js app where I'm posting video data in buffers from electron.

```
app.post("/add/", (req, res) => {
    var user_file = req.body.user_file;
    
    // this initializes a writestream where I can write my buffers and then save this file name in the database

    storage_stream = require("fs").createWriteStream(user_file+'.webm');

// db logic here...

    res.end(JSON.stringify({'success':'added'}))
})
```

above function runs as expected, now I want to post my buffers on 10 seconds interval on another function

```
app.post("/post_buffer/", (req, res) => {
    const user_file = req.body.user_file
    const buffer = Buffer.from(req.body.video_buffer);
      
//    I want to read the existing stream of the user and append the buffers in that stream, something like this

//  if I do something like this
//  const stored_stream = require("fs").createWriteStream(user_file+'.webm');

//  this overwrites the existing file.

    const stored_stream = require("fs").createReadStream(user_file+'.webm');
    stored_stream.write(buffer);     // this throws error, read stream don't have .write() function
    
//  OR
//  stored_stream.push(buffer);      // this doesn't throw any error but makes the file corrupted

    res.end(JSON.stringify({'success':true}))

})
```

Is there any workaround for this? How can I append my buffers in the existing stream?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The file must be opened in append mode from `app.post("/post_buffer/")`. Using append mode will create the file if it does not exist and, in any case, append data to the end of the file.

The different OS file handler flags are documented in the official documentation: [file-system-flags](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-system-flags)

```js
app.post("/post_buffer/", (req, res) => {
    ...
    // Open file handle to append incoming buffer.
    const fileHandle = await fs.promises.open(user_file+'.webm', 'a'); // 'a' -> append mode
    // Initialize a write stream from file handle.
    const stored_stream = fileHandle.createWriteStream();
    // Write the incoming buffer to the write stream and 
    // await the buffer to be flushed.
    await new Promise(resolve => stored_stream.end(buffer, resolve));
   
    ...
})
```